# What to use if I want to run a bluetooth scan and process that data every 2-3 hours even when app is closed?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new to Android and this is my first time working with Bluetooth. I want to make my app scan and get the list of devices in range (Bluetooth, not BLE). Then I want to send this data to a server. This activity needs to be repeated every 2-3 hours. What can I use to accomplish this?
I looked at Alarm Manager and came across the issue that the bluetooth scanning will not work in Doze mode. The same issue is encountered with Work Manager.
Can someone please guide me to resources?

Thank you